# How to generate dynamic UI on the basis of array value in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to generate dynamic UI according to array value.
formfiled is array were am getting below value. I have to generate dynamic ui according to below response .
Now here at index 2 `State of Origin` is coming at 3 `LGA of Origin`. I have to reverse this.
I mean rest anything should come as it. But I have to display `"LGA of Origin"` first and below after that `"State of origin"`.
I can't give array index because it may change. Please help
 // formfield array value is below

```
 formfiled
    0:
    key: "dateOfBirth"
    label: "Date of Birth"
    model: "model.dateOfBirth"
    name: "dateOfBirth"
    placeHolder: "DD/MM/YYYY"
    position: "1"
    required: "true"
    type: "date"
    __typename: "FormFields"
    __proto__: Object
    1:
    key: "lastRechargedAmount"
    label: "Last RCC Amt."
    model: "model.lastRechargedAmount"
    name: "lastRechargedAmount"
    placeHolder: "Amount in Naira"
    position: "2"
    required: "false"
    type: "text"
    __typename: "FormFields"
    __proto__: Object
    2:
    key: "stateOfOrigin"
    label: "State of Origin"
    model: "model.stateOfOrigin"
    name: "stateOfOrigin"
    placeHolder: "State of origin"
    position: "3"
    required: "true"
    type: "parentSelect"
    __typename: "FormFields"
    __proto__: Object
    3:
    key: "lgaOfOrigin"
    label: "LGA of Origin"
    model: "model.lgaOfOrigin"
    name: "lgaOfOrigin"
    placeHolder: "Enter Lga of origin"
    position: "4"
    required: "true"
    type: "childSelect"
    __typename: "FormFields"


    <View style={styles.container}>
                {formFields.map((document, index) => {
                  return (
                      <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: '#fff', padding: 15}}
                      key={index}>
                          {document.type==='text' && (
                          <View style={{  }}>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
                                  <SmallText textColor="grey" text={document.label} />
                                    </View>
                               <Item style={{ borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth: 1, marginLeft: 0 }}>
                                   <Input
                                     value={lastName}
                                      keyboardType='default'
                                       onChangeText={(lastName) =>
                                        this.setState({ lastName: lastName.replace(/\s/g, '') })}
                                                />
                                            </Item>
                                        </View>
                            )
                        }

                          {document.type === 'parentSelect' && (
                            <View  style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                              <SelectField options={stateOptions} value={statesValue}
                              onChange={this.selectedDocument} that={this} 
                              label={document.label}/>
                            </View>

                          )}

                       {document.type === 'childSelect' && (
                          <View style={{  }}>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
                                  <SmallText textColor="grey" text={document.label} />
                                    </View>
                               <Item style={{ borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth: 1, marginLeft: 0 }}>
                                   <Input
                                     value={lgaValue}
                                      keyboardType='default'
                                       onChangeText={(lgaValue) =>
                                        this.setState({ lgaValue: lgaValue.replace(/\s/g, '') })}
                                                />
                                            </Item>
                                        </View>
                            )
                        }

                          {document.type ==='date' && (
                               <View >
                               <View style={{
                                   flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff'
                               }}>
                                   <SmallText textColor="grey" text={document.label} />
                               </View>
                               <Item style={{ borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth: 1, marginLeft: 0 }}>
                                   <DatePicker
                                       minDate={minDate}
                                       maxDate={currentDate}
                                       currentDate={dateOfBirth}
                                       format={format}
                                       width={deviceWidth}
                                       onChange={(dateOfBirth) => this.onChange(dateOfBirth)}
                                       marginLeft={0}
                                   />
                               </Item>
                           </View>
                          )}

                        </View>
                  );
                }
                )}

                  </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map this array to render your UI or use flatlist and pass this data as datasource to get dynamic UI

Comment: I am doing that , actually I have to change the order.. index 3 should come before index 2

Comment: In this case you can make an array of indexes from your data array and apply conditions on the new array by which you can render items in order of your choice.